# How to get address of adjacent cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following vba code to find occurrences of "0" in a following column:

```
For Each c In Range("B:B")

        If c.Value = "0" Then
            MsgBox "0 found at " & (c.Address)
        End If
    Next c
```

How can I modify the code so that when it finds a "0" at say, B6, it displays C7? ie. it display the cell diagonally adjacent to the one where the "0" is found.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about:

```
        MsgBox "0 found at " & Cells(c.Row + 1, c.Column + 1)
```

Comment: Thanks. It works, but I had to make it Cells(c.Row+1,c.Column+1).Address to get the address otherwise it would give me the value.

Answer (score 28):

You can use `Offset`

```
MsgBox "0 found at " & c.Offset(1,1).Address
```

The `Offset` property is of the form `Offset(row, column)`. Examples:

```
Range("B6").Offset(0,0) //refers to cell B6
Range("B6").Offset(1,0) //move one row down (B7)
Range("B6").Offset(0,1) //move one column to the right (C6)
Range("B6").Offset(-1,0) //move one row up (B5)
Range("B6").Offset(0,-1) //move one column to the left (A6)
```