# Having column name X, how to find out what the name X+1 corresponds to?

Tags: excel, vba

Well, this is a pretty straight-forward question:

Having column name X, how to find out what the name X+1 corresponds to?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get address of adjacent cell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626775/how-to-get-address-of-adjacent-cell)

Comment: Well, not really. If I know column name "B", then I would like to know how to find column name "C". Doing Offset would give me the cell address and not the column name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Range Name as you use an normal Address.

For example:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("MyRangeName").Offset(0,1).Value  'If you need the value
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("MyRangeName").Offset(0,1).Address  'If you need the address
```