# Excel 2010: When Cell B1 clicked add contents of adjacent cell (A1, or C1) to another cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm developing an Excel document for my own use, but I've hit a wall in getting everything to work as I want it, I don't really know much VBA, but I understand I'll probably require it to get what I want working... :)

What I need is, for example, when cell B1 is clicked, I want Excel to take the contents of an adjacent cell, (it could be A1 or C1), and duplicate / paste / copy it **into the next blank cell of a row in another sheet**.

I'd preferably like it to be flexible, so that I can simply duplicate it for B2 (and it would then apply for A2 or C2), since it would be required for hundreds of cells - and entering it manually constantly would be a total pain. I don't really want to use forms or check boxes...

Thanks!,
Luke.

Comment: So... you've "hit the wall"  but you haven't put much effort to get over or around it, have you?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626775/how-to-get-address-of-adjacent-cell/4627007#4627007) about using `Range.offset`

Comment: @mjv. Wow, what did I do to deserve that snarky comment? Is it because I have a limited knowledge of VBA? Or because I'm a newbie to this site? None of those gives you any valid reason to bash me like that. I could've written, "I've hit a wall, and I have searched and searched the internet using specific Google search terms, and tried various measures without VBA in Excel already", but that would be beside the point since it doesn't benefit the relevance of my question. I've tried being nice. I came here for an answer, not an argument. :(

Comment: @jonsca. Thanks! That is what I am looking for regarding selecting an adjacent cell, which is only the first part of my multi step problem. I still wouldn't know how to copy the cell's contents and move it to another cell. Also, since I am lacking at VBA, I don't know how or where to insert that section of code in Excel. :)

Comment: @Luke While it may not have been the best or kindest presentation, the idea of what mjv said is true.  Few people are going to want to walk you through this inch by inch.  I would be happy to help you, but it's much easier if you come to the table with: "Okay, I've looked up copying and pasting, I've implemented the example, but nothings begin pasted in."  It gives people something more to work with is all.  Look at the "Related" frame on the right side, and it should give you some threads to start with.  Have a go at it and reformulate your question a bit.

Comment: @Luke. Welcome to SO, and please accept my apologies for a snide and on the whole unhelpful comment.  What prompted this comment was the overall `send-me-the-codez` quality of the question, coupled with the fact that the "hit the wall" statement didn't appears to be supported by the information supplied in the question. You are -partially- right: the amount of effort you have put in searching for a solution doesn't relate to the legitimacy or the relevance of the question. However, by providing more insight into what you have read and/or tried one fosters better responses because ..

Comment: ... the potential responders use this extra information to better frame the question. @jonsca explained this in his [much kinder and more helpful] comment.  The difficuly that you may have encountered -and this can happen to anyone in various domains- is that you are generally open to _any_ solution.  When knowing so little about a particular domain one often asks questions which are difficult to answer [without producing a extensive lecture on the state of the art]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstood your question but I'd go about it like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim WS As Worksheet: Set WS = Worksheets(2)
    Dim adjacent As Range: Set adjacent = Target.Offset(0, 1)
    WS.Range(adjacent.Address).Value = adjacent.Value
End Sub
```