# Jumping n cell (down/ up/ to the right/ to the left) from a certain cell

Tags: excel, vba

can you help me with this question: "How to jump n cell (down/ up/ to the right/ to the left) from a certain cell in ms excel, where n is an integer".

[question figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rR7Sd.png)

I want to make a macro and if i run that macro, a window will open and shows four options as shown in the figure. Lets say initially B3 is selected then if I type 6 in the input and click button "below" B9 will selected.

I've tried so many option in Excel but cannot figure it out and I am fairly new to  vba.

I am sorry for my bad english, please help, thanks!

Comment: Could you please let me know jump means ?

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626775/how-to-get-address-of-adjacent-cell/4627007#4627007)

Comment: @PASUMPONVN I've added a figure to make my question more clear. please have a look.

Comment: @AlexP thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the `Offset()` function for that:

```
ActiveCell.Offset(1 ,0).Activate // jump one row futher
ActiveCell.Offset(-1,0).Activate // jump one row back
ActiveCell.Offset(0 ,1).Activate // jump one column further
ActiveCell.Offset(0,-1).Activate // jump one column back
```

Obviously you can jump rows and columns at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

The below code takes input value from C4 .

It is for down program, Similarly you can do it for right or left for column

```
Sub Program_Down()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Lastrow As Long
    Dim Str1 As String
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    inputval = ws.Range("C4").Value

    Set inputadd = ws.Range("C4")

    Addres = inputadd.Address
    Set Rng = ws.UsedRange
    For Each c In Rng
        If Len(c.Value) > 0 Then
            If c.Address <> inputadd.Address Then
                Row1 = c.Row
                col = c.Column
                Value = c.Value
                ws.Cells(inputval + Row1, col).Value = Value
                c.Value = ""
                Exit For
            End If
        End If

    Next

    End Sub
```

Comment: While this context may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @PASUMPON thanks for the response, when i run your code nothing is happen.